# Imported list is double bracketed when printed?

Tags: python, list

I am importing a list of strings into python from a text file. When I print the list to check it has been done properly, I see it is double bracketed.

From what I understand this means it multidimensional but this is not what I want. How do I prevent this?

An example of my code is shown below.

```
test_list_a_file = "path/to/test_list_a_file"


with open(test_list_a_file, 'r') as openfile:
    test_list_a = [line.split() for line in openfile.readlines()]

print(test_list_a[0:4])
```

This returns...

```
[['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['D']]
```

When I manually create my list in python to see what happens:

```
test_list_b = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
print(test_list_b[0:4])
```

It works just fine...

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

The file `test_list_a_file` looks like this:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Whats wrong with the way I am importing it?

Comment: try `line.strip` instead of `line.split`

Comment: Did `line.strip()` work for you? its job is to get rid of whitespace and newlines and appears to be what you want. `line.split()` turns the string into a list.

Comment: @Joran Beasley, thank you, if you add that as an answer I can mark it as correct. I know it's a simple question but I was genuinely confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test_list_a_file = "path/to/test_list_a_file"
with open(test_list_a_file, 'r') as openfile:
    test_list_a = [line.strip() for line in openfile.readlines()]
```

should work

or alternatively

```
with open(test_list_a_file, 'r') as openfile:
     test_list_a = openfile.read().split()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a loop
like this:

```
`for i in range(0,5):

    print(test_list_b[i])`
```

output:

```
A 
B
C
D
E
F
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `line.split('\n')` It will detect the Value after Enter in the text file.